# Switched to AppCompat theme now search bar changed

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I added Theme.Appcompat to my application and and now the search icon and the blue line are gone from my search bar. Does anybody know how to get the Holo theme to work with the Theme.Appcompat

[image: Search bar desired]

[image: Search bar current]

Comment: just make the toolbar transparent

Comment: That is not the problem.

Comment: as much as i know.. if you use appcompact library, u need to use app compact themes only

Comment: I am but I am not getting the right looking search bar for some reason.

Comment: can you share your toolbar code?

Comment: I am using an actionbar

Comment: I actually can't as this is company code

Comment: you'll have to use toolbar with Appcompact. wait a while

Answer (score 0):

follow material design guidelines when using appcompact library

use a toolbar and add your views to it, style it as per your needs, i just made gradient for timebeing.

[image]

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@drawable/mygradient"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:weightSum="1">
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Search for videos"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon"
                    android:layout_weight="0.86" />
            </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

change the accent color to your holo blue

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```